# Google Script: Looping If Else Array Through Rows

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, google-apps-script, typeerror

I am trying to create a simple function for google scripts which takes 4 columns data and loops through them with an if else statement. It takes the first value that isn't equal to 0 and subtracts them from a 5th column. It does this through each row of one of the sheets, and pasts the results in 6th column. I keep getting `"TypeError: Cannot find function foreach in object."`

My assumption is that I am not storing the Array correctly? I cannot embed pictures as I have no feedback yet. Here is the code, and a link to sample data, if you need more to be placed here please let me know.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/182C95mMxWlw4qqiEoVI3RjDJnXpUItk0TwS33amg1zE/edit?usp=sharing.

For the data, `Line 6`, would need to ignore `I6`, and take `J6` and subtract it from `M6`, then paste the results in `P6`.

```
function waterFallCalculator() 
{
  var deltaRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("4/18"),
      res = [];
  deltaRange.getRange(30, 9, 200, 5).getValues().forEach(function(row)
  {
    res.push([row.reduce(function (a, b, c, d, e)
    {
      if(!isNaN(a))
      {
        return (a - e);
      }
      else if(isNaN(a))
      {
        return (b - e);
      }
      else if(isNaN(b))
      {
        return(c - e);
      }
      else if(isNaN(c))
      {
        return(d - e);
      }
    })]);
  });
  return deltaRange.getRange(30, 16, 200, 1).setValues(res);
}
```

Comment: use camel case in forEach()  - you wrote foreach(), hence the error

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed that one. Still having an issue where I get #NUM! This at least got it to run again

Comment: @BrendonReynolds you should edit this question to reflect the error you get, and remove the now-inaccurate information about the resolved `forEach` issue. As far as resolving this `#NUM` issue, consider what is needed in order for your `if-else if` chain to reach the 3rd test. (Hint: it's unreachable)

Comment: I could not find ``getSheetByName("4/18")`` from your sample spreadsheet. I think that in the case of your script, showing the input and output values you want will help users think of your issue. Input value is the value retrieved by ``deltaRange.getRange(30, 9, 200, 5).getValues()``. Output value is ``res``. Can you provide the simple sample values? And the arguments of ``Array.prototype.reduce()`` is 4. So I think that in your script, ``e`` of ``function (a, b, c, d, e)`` becomes ``undefined``. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Thanks to tehhowch I will make those adjustments. Also @Tanaike in my sample code I referenced the data as such "For the data, Line 6, would need to ignore I6, and take J6 and subtract it from M6, then paste the results in P6."

Comment: Thank you for replying. I’m sorry about my poor English.